# Processing lots of data through a pipe with python / popen

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I'm trying to watch a process and wait for a certain pattern, say:

```
open someFile id=123
```

then, after that, I want to wait for

```
close id=123
```

I tried to write the script as follows:

```
running_procs = [Popen(["process", "and", "options"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)]

while running_procs:
    for proc in running_procs:
        retcode = proc.poll()
        if retcode is not None: # Process finished.
            running_procs.remove(proc)
            break
        else:
            while True:
                next_line = proc.stdout.readline()
                if next_line == '' and proc.poll() != None:
                    break
                m = re.search( r'someFile.*id\=([0-9]*)', next_line, re.M|re.I)
                if m:
                  print m.group(1)
```

But it seems to be performing way too slow.  Any suggestions on handling a lot of lines in a pipe?  Is there a faster way?

Comment: have you tried profiling it? python -m cProfile -s time myscript.py (if I remember correctly)

Comment: When you claim its too slow, are you saying that the process is producing output quickly but your read approach is processing the pipe too slow?

Comment: By "too slow," I mean that the lines appeared to be buffering and that python appeared to be processing it too slowly.  What ended up being the actual case was that, as you pointe out in your answer, the buffer size was too high.  Setting it to 1 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in this specific example to indicate that it should be slow simply on account of the code. With only a single process in your list, its going to read lines as fast as the process makes them available. This means the code is going to be dependent on the subprocess flushing its output and making lines available. But thats really to be expected.

Since you are going to always be reading line by line, you might want to set `bufsize=1` in your Popen, to make sure its always line buffered:

```
Popen(["process"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1)
```

I do however see an issue if you intend to be running multiple processes, as indicated by the fact that you are using a list of possible processes and popping dead ones from them. Your loop is going to block on one process at a time. If this is not your intention to have the processes read serially, then it will be a cause of a slow down in how you get your data back. They run in parallel, but only be monitored serially.

Aside from this, you will have to go into more detail about why you consider the results to be slow and what you expect to happen.